# Vim generating numbers in ascending order

Tags: vim, automation

I have the current block of code I'm playing around with.

```
<h1>This is h#</h1>
<h2>This is h</h2>
<h3>This is h</h3>
<h4>This is h</h4>
<h5>This is h</h5>
<h6>This is h</h6>
```

I wanted to insert numbers according to their line all at once so I was wondering how to insert numbers after the h marked by a # across multiple lines, to get the result:

```
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h2>This is h2</h2>
<h3>This is h3</h3>
<h4>This is h4</h4>
<h5>This is h5</h5>
<h6>This is h6</h6>
```

Thank you!

Comment: what version of Vim?

Answer (score 8):

Vim 8 ( and a number of Vim emulations )

I'd start with

```
<h1>This is h0</h1>
<h2>This is h0</h2>
<h3>This is h0</h3>
<h4>This is h0</h4>
<h5>This is h0</h5>
<h6>This is h0</h6>
```

then on the top 0 of h0.  I'd block highlight with `CTRL-V`

go down to the bottom 0 of the h6 tag with  `5j`

then type `g` and then `CTRL-A`

and it will be what you want

Answer (score 2):

I would do this

```
 :for i in range(1,6) | put='<h'.i'.'>This is h'.i.'</h'.i.'>' | endfor
 :1d
```

We are concatening string with the variable 'i'. Tha's why we are using the dot 
on the put statement

More explanation - If you want simple to put a string on the first line:

```
 :0put='my string'
```

A second way to increase numbers automatically is:

Let's consider you already have this code and the first line coincides with the first line of the actual archive you want to change.

```
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h1>This is h1</h1>

:2,$s,\d\+,\=line('.'),g
```

If by any chance those lines are in another place you can make something like:

```
:5,9s,\d\+,\=line('.')-3,g
```

OBS: the use of the `line('.')` comes in handy because it is naturally an increasing sequence of numbers.

A third way to insert an ascending sequence is:
In normal mode type:

`6i<h1>This is h1</h1>`  <kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

The above action will insert 6 lines like this:

```
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h1>This is h1</h1>
```

Now put the cursor at the first 1 on the second line and make a visual block
selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, then extend the selection till the last line, like seen below:

[image]

Now press <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

Now press <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to jump to the next number and repeat the action. Finally press <kbd>;</kbd> to jump to the last number and then <kbd>.</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

With my [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355), you just need to yank the first `<h1>This is h1</h1>` line, and then paste 5 times with `5gPp`, which pastes with all decimal numbers incremented by 1. This also is repeatable via `.`, so you could have also pasted just once and then repeat that 4 times. There are also mapping variants that decrement, increment just one number, and many more mappings around paste variations.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'll use macro to generate numbers in order.

In this case, I'll write `<h1>This is h1</h1>` first.

1. `qq`, (first `q` is to start recording your keystroke and store it as a macro in key `q`)
2. `yyp`, to duplicate the line (`yy` to copy current line, `p` to paste)
3. `ctrl-a`, to increase first occurred number which is from `<h1>`
4. `w` then `ctrl-a`, to jump to the next word and then increase the second occurred which is h1`
5. repeat step 4 again to increase `</h1>`
6. `q`, to stop recording
7. `4@q`, to redo your recording four more times (`@` from `shift+2`, means to execute macro, `q` specified the macro function stored in key `q`, and `4` means do the action 4 times)

Answer (score 0):

Will it be okay to copy the `h1, h2, ...` column and paste?

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> and select `h1` and then `5j`. This will block select next 5 line, Change number accordingly. 
Copy the selected lines using y.

Now, nagivate to `h` where you want to past and repeat <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> and `5j`, Thereafter finish the paste with <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>